# Proof of A Proposition on Dumit and Foote's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I am reading Section 2.3 of Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition, and am having a hard time proving the following proposition on page 57:

> Let $H=\langle x\rangle$ and assume $|x|=n<\infty$. Then $H=\langle x^a\rangle$ if and only if $(a,n)=1$, where $(a,n)$ denotes the greatest common devisor of $a$ and $n$.

My attempt;

If $H=\langle x^a\rangle$, then by Prop. 2, $|H|=|x^a|$. Since $H=\langle x\rangle$, Prop. 2 implies $|H|=|x|=n$. So we have $|x^a|=n$. By Prop. 5, $|x^a|=\dfrac{n}{(n, a)}$. This and $|x^a|=n$ imply $(n,a)=1$.

Conversely, suppose $(n,a)=1$. Then by Prop. 5, $|x^a|=\dfrac{n}{(n,a)}=n=|x|$. Since $H=\langle x\rangle$, $|x^a|=|x|=|H|$. 
From here, how do I proceed to show $H=\langle x^a\rangle$?

> **Proposition 2**. If $H=\langle x\rangle$, then $|H|=|x|$.
>
> **Proposition 5**. Let $G$ be a group, let $x\in G$ and let $a\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$. If $|x|=n<\infty$, then $|x^a|=\dfrac{n}{(n,a)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you heard of Bezout's identity? It states that there exists $r,s$ integers so that $n\cdot r + a\cdot s=1$. Now try to use this to show $x^{as}=x^1=x$, and from that conclude $H=\langle x^a\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: How do you conclude from $x^{as}=x$ that $H=\langle x^a\rangle$?

Comment: @kmiyazaki the definition of $H$ is $H=\{1,x,x^2,...\}$; as sets, clearly $H\supset \langle x^a\rangle$, so you just have to show the reverse inclusion

Comment: I figure it out. Thank you so much for your help.